# jQuery performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

imagine you have to do DOM manipulation like a lot (in my case, it's kind of a dynamic list).

Look at this example:

```
var $buffer = $('<ul/>', {
                'class': '.custom-example',
  'css':  {
   'position':  'absolute',
   'top':   '500px'
  }
           });

$.each(pages[pindex], function(i, v){
 $buffer.append(v);
});

$buffer.insertAfter($root);
```

"pages" is an array which holds LI elements as jQuery object.

"$root" is an UL element

What happens after this code is, both UL's are animated (scrolling) and finally, within the callback of animate this code is executed:

```
$root.detach();
$root = $buffer;
$root.css('top', '0px');
$buffer = null;
```

This works very well, the only thing I'm pi**ed off is the performance. I do cache
all DOM elements I'm laying a hand on.
Without looking too deep into jQuery's source code, is there a chance that my performance issues are located there?

Does jQuery use DocumentFragments to append things?

If you create a new DOM element with

```
var new = $('<div/>')
```

it is only stored in memory
at this point isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem just a few days ago. Its much faster if you do it this way:

```
var buffer = $('<ul class="custom-example" style="position: absolute; top:500px"></ul>')

var html = ''

$.each(pages[pindex], function(i, v){
   html += v
});

buffer.html(html)

buffer.insertAfter($root);
```

(be careful: in your example buffer is already a jquery object, you don't need to reslect it for the insertAfter)

Comment: well, it indeed is faster to do it that way. Unfortuantly, I can't do it because pages[pindex] contains jQuery objects with .data and event handlers. but +1 anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about performance, you should construct you whole `<ul>` element with all `<li>` subelements as a string. Use "**+=**" operation for the string concatenations. At the end use jQuery to insert constructed string inside your web page.

See http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/09/string-performance-an-analysis/ about string performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [slide from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#5) (jQuery creator) where he says that jQuery does in fact use document fragments internally. On the following slides he explains briefly how to build up a lightweight document fragment and append it in one operation stating that this "[ends up being really fast](http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#7)". You might want to look into that, if you did not already (as you mention document fragments yourself).

As for the process of creating new elements with `$('<div>')`, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) says:

> But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these elements.

jQuery uses "the native JavaScript createElement() function" if you provide a single tag and "the browser's innerHTML mechanism" for more complex html snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Creating DOM nodes one by one is usually slower than creating a HTML string and let the browser process it (via innerHTML). Here are [more details](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html) about this.